# How to set s3a configuration correctly in hadoop configuration?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I get strange errors such as - cant't get aws credentials or Unable to load credentials from ...

Is there any way to set explicitly the s3a credentials in hadoop configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As s3a is relatively new implementation (and works correctly from hadoop 2.7), you need to set to sets properties in hadoop configuration -

```
    conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key);
    conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key);
```

(conf is hadoop configuration)

Comment: I did not get the reason but it solved my issue.

conf.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", access_key); // not working
conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key);  //worked

Comment: Do you know what version made the config name to change?